# Azure Api Management: How to count amount of requests without Subscription Header

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

My users using AAM API endpoint for a third-party service that requires a webhook - and I need to show usage of this endpoint in User Reports

Third-party API does not support headers and I can't pass `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key` user subscription key to it, and the request will be called anonymously.
As far as I understand that will not allow counting that request in User Reports.

[image: Endpoint settings]

But I can use a token URI parameter to manually get `subscription-id` and keys for it, with `send-request` policy.
If I do this is there a way to add the `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key` header to (running?) request in order to perform it on behalf of user subscription?

So far, I can only think about wrapping the required request in another AAM request which will use `send-request` and `set-header` policies like that

```
> POST /endpoint/telegram/public/token123
>> <send-request>GET /token123/keys/primary</send-request>
> POST /endpoint/telegram/token123 +H 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key:key123'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I returned to this question after a couple of days and feel extremely embarrassing now.

To perform a request on behalf of the User I can use the API key in the query instead of the header, there are literally separate setting for that
[image]

That solves everything.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to integrate with Application insight to monitor details : [How to integrate Azure API Management with Azure Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-app-insights#performance-implications-and-log-sampling)

Also, you can leverage the [metrices to analyze the request pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-use-azure-monitor#view-metrics-of-your-apis).

Based on any condition you may create alert to notify you as well : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-use-azure-monitor

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have my tools to monitor requests, and I can use them - but a user can't. The target I'm trying to achieve is to provide the user with stat information about the basically anonymous request that was made on his behalf through uri token instead of the header.

Comment: If there are a set of authorized users, then you may try this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-use-azure-monitor - creating a group who would receive notifications/ monitoring log details based on conditions or not. Also, I see you are using API key to get the details in an API call for the users.